# Returning an NSMutableArray in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been trying to work out how to return an MSMutableArray in objective c, I have this code here.

```
- (NSMutableArray*)generateRandomNumber{
NSMutableArray *unqArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
int randNum;
int counter = 0;
while (counter< 6) {
    randNum = arc4random_uniform(40.0);
    if (![unqArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randNum]]) {
        [unqArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randNum]];
        counter++;
    }
}
return unqArray;
}

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
*results = generateRandomNumber();
}
```

This is my code at the moment, where it says,

```
NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

I get the following errors...

> - Implicit declaration of function 'generateRandomNumber' is invalid in C99
> - Assigning to 'NSMutableArray' from incompatible type 'int'

If anybody is willing to show me my mistake and help me out as well as many others I will appreciate it as much as possible.

Thanks to all who help me out!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`generateRandomNumber` is a method, not a C function, so use `[self generateRandomNumber]` to call it, and you are assigning `results` incorrectly, so:

```
results = [self generateRandomNumber];
```

Alternatively if you want to define it as a C function, use:

```
NSMutableArray *generateRandomNumber() {
    ...
}
```

Also, as pointed-out by @Larme, there is no need to allocate `results` before assigning it from `generateRandomNumber`.

Comment: There is also a double alloc/init.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is more first ever time on stack overflow and I am amazed at your answer, thanks for answering my question as stupid as it probably is. I am only a newbie so I appreciate your help to the max! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
 NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 results = [self generateRandomNumber];
}
```

Or more simply:

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
 NSMutableArray *results = [self generateRandomNumber];
 // Do something with this Array
}
```

Though you should consider a different name for that method as currently it sounds like it is returning one number, not an array of random numbers.

Comment: Not exactly more simply... The first option creates and then destroys an instance for no reason so you shouldn't do that

Comment: Thanks, I had that second suggestion at first but I went to what I had because I thought that was what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

When calling/using a function in Objective-C
it's `[self generateRandomNumber]`

When you declare a variables it's `NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` and use if like `results = mutableArry`, `*` before it is not needed..

about your problem, you better do it like this:

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender 
{
    NSMutableArray *results = [self generateRandomNumber];
}
```

you dont need to allocate anymore, because you are passing an mutable array that is already allocated..

Answer (score 1):

Your method `generateRandomNumbers` should work as expect the problem is here:

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
*results = generateRandomNumber();
}
```

The first thing is that you are creating an unneeded mutable array, second your are trying to substitute the value of the pointer that points to result array, third `generateRandonNumber` is a method not a function you should call it like `[self generateRandomNumber]`.
Also I would implement a optimization since I'm pretty sure that you are not going to modify the random number array, the returned instance should be an immutable copy.
Here the final code:

```
- (NSArray*)generateRandomNumber{
NSMutableArray *unqArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
int randNum;
int counter = 0;
while (counter< 6) {
    randNum = arc4random_uniform(40.0);
    if (![unqArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randNum]]) {
        [unqArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randNum]];
        counter++;
    }
}
return unqArray.copy;
}

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
NSArray *results = nil;
results = [self generateRandomNumber];
}
```

Comment: If you return a copy make sure the method signature's return type is also `NSArray`.

Comment: i prefer using `[NSArray arrayWithArray:unqArray];` to return an NSArray for that one..

Comment: Since the release of ARC I don't think that it makes a great difference, but using -arrayWithArray if unqArray is nil it will generate an empty array, with copy you just get nil again.

Answer (score 0):

Your generateRandomNumbers method should work with no problem, but in the IBAction there you try to put an INT directly into the array, you need to wrap it in an NSNumber like you have in the other method there

Comment: Where does he put an  Int directly into the array in his IBAction? I only see a statement assigning the result of a function to a pointer to an array (which is completely wrong) but I don't get you point.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is correct.
What you are doing wrong is here: `*results = generateRandomNumber();`

- There is no need of an `*` here,because in this way you are trying to assign the pointer address of your array to `results` object.
- Secondly you are trying to call an `Objective-C` method in `C` syntax.
  So the correct syntax would be: `results = [self generateRandomNumber];`

Comment: Thanks, I'm kind of used to swift were it was

Comment: results = generateRandomNumber();

Comment: So that's what made me do that.

Comment: i don't have much experience of swift. But thats how you call a method in objective-c